# ColdFusion IPv6 to 128-bit unsigned int

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I needed to create a function that could convert an IPv6 address to its numeric representation.

Working with IPv4 is pretty straight forward as it uses an 32-bit unsigned int for its numerical representation.  IPv6 is represented by an 128-bit unsigned int.  That size of a number is too large for the builtin ColdFusion bit logic functions to use.

This function must make use of the underlying Java system to make the conversion.

Need a function to do the reverse: [ColdFusion 128-bit unsigned int to IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203963/coldfusion-128-bit-unsigned-int-to-ipv6)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe?

Comment: @ScottJibben - Not sure why all the down votes, but ... maybe reword the above so it sounds more like "question"? i.e. Like "I am trying to do X and tried code Y code, but am getting result Z instead of {blank}". That would probably be a better fit with S.O.'s format.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that I wrote to transform an IPv6 address to a 128-bit unsigned int.

```
<cffunction name="IPv6ToUInt128" returntype="numeric" output="no" access="public" hint="returns uint128 number for IPv6 address">
    <cfargument name="vcIPv6" type="string" required="yes" hint="IPv6 address">

    <cfif arguments.vcIPv6 EQ "">
        <cfreturn 0>
    </cfif>

    <cfset local['javaMathBigInteger'] = CreateObject("java", "java.math.BigInteger")>
    <cfset local['javaNetInetAddress'] = CreateObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>
    <cftry>
        <cfset local['uint128'] = local.javaMathBigInteger.init(1, local.javaNetInetAddress.getByName(arguments.vcIPv6).getAddress()).toString()>
        <cfreturn local.uint128>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfreturn 0>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

If you have any suggestions to improve this code, please leave comments.

Comment: This should be `<cfscript>`